# adding animation to view in ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I followed this link:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview

Similarly, I did:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" name="OutletMenu" title="OutletMenu" class="page kitchenmenu">
<div class="header-bar>
<ion-content>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

style.css

In CSS: If I have sliding effect on classes, `.kitchenmenu.ng-enter` and `.kitchenmenu.ng-leave`, It does not get applied.

However, If I have

`.ng-enter` and `.ng-leave`,

The header part of html has the animation but not the `ion-content`. I need to have `kitchenmenu` animation on full page. What seems wrong and why I am not able to use it?

```
/* PAGES
============================================================================= */
.kitchenmenu  { }
.bill   {  }


/* ANIMATIONS
============================================================================= */

.page.ng-leave  { z-index:9999; }
.page.ng-enter  { z-index:8888; }

/* page specific animations ------------------------ */


.kitchenmenu.ng-leave      {
  -webkit-animation:slideInDown 0.5s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation:slideInDown 0.5s both ease-in;
  animation: slideInDown 0.5s both ease-in;
}
.kitchenmenu.ng-enter    { 
  -webkit-animation:slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation:slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;
  animation:slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;  
}

/* slide in from the bottom */
@keyframes slideInUp {
  from  { transform:translateY(100%); }
  to    { transform: translateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideInUp {
  from  { -moz-transform:translateY(100%); }
  to    { -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
  from  { -webkit-transform:translateY(100%); }
  to    { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
}

/*slide from top */

@keyframes slideInDown {
  from  { transform:translateY(0); }
  to    { transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideInDown {
  from  { -moz-transform:translateY(0); }
  to    { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInDown {
  from  { -webkit-transform:translateY(0); }
  to    { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
```